# Entity Framework and Linq syntax

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to do a select where the final two letters of an id match whats in a string enumerable passed to the method but i;m getting the syntax wrong

I'm trying to get it down to something along these lines

```
setHeaders.SET_ID.Substring(setHeaders.SET_ID.Length - 2).ToUpper().Any(x => setIds.Contains(x.ToString()) )
```

Heres the whole method at the moment

```
var tupleResponse = (from setHeaders in _woEntities.SETHEADER
                            join setDetails in _woEntities.SETDETAIL on setHeaders.SET_ID equals setDetails.SET_ID
                            join workOrders in _woEntities.B1PERMIT on new
                            {
                                setDetails.B1_PER_ID1,
                                setDetails.B1_PER_ID2,
                                setDetails.B1_PER_ID3
                            } equals new { workOrders.B1_PER_ID1, workOrders.B1_PER_ID2, workOrders.B1_PER_ID3 }
                            where setDetails.REC_STATUS == "A" && /*setHeaders.SET_ID.Substring(setHeaders.SET_ID.Length - 2).ToUpper().Any(x => setIds.Contains(x.ToString()) )*/
                                  (setHeaders.SET_ID.Substring(setHeaders.SET_ID.Length - 2).ToUpper() == "OS" ||
                                   setHeaders.SET_ID.Substring(setHeaders.SET_ID.Length - 2).ToUpper() == "TR")  &&
                                   workOrders.B1_APPL_STATUS.ToLower() == "open"
                            select new
                            {

                                setHeaders.SET_ID,
                                setHeaders.SET_TITLE,
                                workOrders.B1_ALT_ID
                            }).AsEnumerable()
           .Select(x => Tuple.Create(x.SET_ID, x.SET_TITLE, x.B1_ALT_ID))
           .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your latest testing would work better with `.EndsWith`

```
setHeaders.SET_ID.ToUpper().EndsWith("TR")
```

LINQ often can't translate `.Contains` for a local collection, but if it could I don't think you would need `.Any` or `.ToString()` (you know its a string).

**May not work**

```
setIds.Contains(setHeaders.SET_ID.Substring(setHeaders.SET_ID.Length - 2).ToUpper())
```

If it doesn't, you need to look into LINQKit and PredicateBuilder.

Comment: Sorry i think we may be talking about different points, i'd like to extend the function so i don't have to hardcode "TR" or "OS"

I'd like to be able to pass in a collection of "endings" (a naming convention the business uses to differentiate different groups) and be able to match the end of SET_ID with a value in that list

Comment: Can you try the statement I put in  to see if it works with your LINQ provider? If not, that is where PredicateBuilder comes in.

Comment: ahhhhh dummy, sorry that was my bad, i misread that. This code seems to work! thanks

  
  setIds.Contains(setHeaders.SET_ID.Substring(setHeaders.SET_ID.Length - 2).ToUpper())